# How can I open a local file with a variable link in HTML JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have xxx(1).xml, xxx(2).xml, and xxx(3).xml files. I'm trying to open these files in a JavaScript function. I used this code

`href="xxx.xml"`

in HTML, but it only works for one local file. And I also tried in JavaScript:

`window.open(path, "_self")`

But this isn't working like I want. Is there a method for this?

Comment: Did you try using full path in href ??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].   If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: i tried my path just didnt write here because its long

Answer (score 1):

You **can not** open local files in the browser through JavaScript. since it causes security issues.

Comment: yes u can if u call this files in html reach that button or id with javascript

Comment: i've done this but im trying to reach them all with one function

Comment: with for loop  varible